# Clone a git repo from a Debian server to laptop

Tags: git, debian

I have a debian server setup in my house with webmin installed and I'm currently using it to develop my apps as a testing server. I want to know if there is a way to clone the git repo to my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have configured ssh connection with debian server
Just clone:

```
git clone debian:path/to/your/repo
```